# trying to get specific bytes from config file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I have a bit of a problem. I need to be able to have specific bytes set in a config file and then use them in a python 3 program to control logic based on a byte sent to a raspberry pi via UART.

My issue is that when i get the property from the config file with:

```
config = ConfigParser() 
config.read("/home/pi/dspp/dspp.properties") 
propertyOne = config.get("configFileSection", "nameOfPropertyInConfigFile")
```

the property is `0x12` and comes through as a string and i cannot get it to be of the correct type. when i just do  `print("0x12")`  i get `18` (which is correct) but when i do `print(propertyOne)` i get `0x12`

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was as simple as doing:

`propertyOne = (int(config.get("configFileSection", "nameOfPropertyInConfigFile"), 16))`

where i was going wrong is not supplying the int with base 16 and of cause the getint() method on configParser doesn't have scope to provide one